# is Android Application remain alive after backpressed default behavior

Tags: android, application-lifecycle

I have Application class with a static object like this:

```
public class FootballApp extends Application {
//.......
public static Membership membership;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    membership = new Membership();
    //......
}
```

}

and the Manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".FootballApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        ......

</application>
```

and i have n't override the onBackPressed at any activity
so when i press back button pop up from back stack til its empty and back to the home screen
my question is :
what happened to the application 'FootballApp' class after back pressed, because in my case when i open the my app again all the static Fields in the FootballApp class remain the same 
does it mean my application still running in the background ?

Comment: That `Application` subclass is alive as long as your application's process is running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you press back by default the Activity is finished.  The Application is not.  In Android an Application is only terminated when the OS runs out of resources and decides to kill it.